# Clear and reset currency formatting

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following code to clear and reset the formatting on a range of cells.

`firstRow` and `lastRow` are correctly set.

Some cells are not correctly formatted. I find those cells is by looking for a missing "€" sign.

The only way I know to fix this is to double-click the cell.   Afterwards the "€" sign appears and the calculations work again.

Do you know a smarter solution and a way to detect and debug this?

```vb
' Amount in EUR
Dim amountInEurRange As Range
Set amountInEurRange = Full.Range(f_amountInEUR & firstRow & ":" & f_amountInEUR & lastRow)
amountInEurRange.ClearFormats
amountInEurRange.Select
With Selection
    .NumberFormat = "#,##0.00 [$€-de-DE]"
    .Value = .Value
End With
```

[image]

Comment: What are your system separators? Also, just curious but are you forcing left aligment in cells? How is this aligment right after executing line `amountInEurRange.ClearFormats`?

Comment: You are right, the problem is somehow related to the separator. The problem only occurs, if numbers have decimal values. To be honest, I don't know what my system separators are. I'm located in Germany, but the OS is in English (US). And yes, I'm forcing left alignment, but this is not part of the code snippet.

Comment: [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/change-the-character-used-to-separate-thousands-or-decimals-c093b545-71cb-4903-b205-aebb9837bd1e) you can read how to chek your separators. Also, I'm asking about the aligment because when there is no format in a cell (standard), numbers and dates are right aligned by default and text are left aligned, so if Excel aligns a number to left, it means it's not being recognized as a numeric value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously, Excel didn't recognize the second value as number and stored it as text. A text has no numeric value and therefore is not added up in the `Sum`-function. A text will also not be formatted.

First thing is you need to understand the difference between *value* and *format* of a cell. A numeric value is internally stored in a binary format. This value is then displayed in a human readable form. The value `1234` can be displayed as `1234`, as `1.234,00`, as `1,234.0`, as `€1,234.0` or `1.23E+03` and so on. Formatting will not change it's internal value.

Second thing is you need to understand how Excel works if you enter some data. You enter the keys <kbd>1</kbd> <kbd>8</kbd> <kbd>2</kbd> <kbd>1</kbd> <kbd>,</kbd> <kbd>3</kbd> <kbd>7</kbd> and presses <kbd>Enter</kbd>. If on your computer (not in Excel!) the regional settings define the decimal character as comma, Excel will see your input as number and convert it to its internal binary value. It then looks at the formatting of the cell and displays it accordingly. If however, your decimal character is a dot, Excel will not see your input as number and therefore store the input as string. A string is stored in a complete different way (put it simple: Every character is one byte).

Of course the reality is more complicated, Excel will also check the formatting when it receives your input. If you format a cell as date, it will try to interpret your input as date, again by checking it against the regional settings. Formatting the cell as text will store the input as text, even if it could be converted to a number.

Now somehow the data in your sheet was entered and Excel didn't interpret is as number. Either someone with different regional settings entered it, or maybe it was imported from a CSV. What happens when you double-click the cell is that Excel handle the content as if you just entered it - and on your PC it *can* be interpreted as number and therefore is converted. Looks similar or equal, but is a complete different value.

What you could do is to add the following code to your routine, it will try to convert a string into a number

```
For Each cell In amountInEurRange
    If VarType(cell.Value) = vbString Then
        Dim s As String, v As Variant
        s = cell.Value
        On Error Resume Next
        v = CDbl(Replace(s, ",", ".")) ' In VBA, decimal char is always "."
        On Error GoTo 0
        If VarType(v) = vbDouble Then cell.Value = v
    End If
Next cell
```

Comment: Thank you so much, FunThomas. Your explanation helps a lot and your code also. Unfortunately this means for me to manually check 1000 cells, because sometimes the comma has shifted. :D This means, today sucks. But tomorrow I'll hapy.